# Student allocation in campus project. Looping through an sorted array of objects from database, filter it and perform actions to accommodate students

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, recursion, sequelize.js

First of all, hello everyone. I've been searching and looking on stack overflow for almost 1.5years but this is my first question here. Thanks in advance for your attention.

So, my application is about students and their allocation on university campus based on their university, number of available spaces and grade in the first place and based on type of study, gender and year of study in second place, in order to be assigned to a room in the dormitory and to find out the roommates.

Until now, I managed to create the database and the relation between tables. I am using node js,express, mysql with sequelize ORM for backend to build a RestApi that is going to be used in frontend, where my application is build with React and Redux to manage the global state. The auth system is working, students can sign in or sign up, fill in all the information needed to create an enrollment action, which is collecting their meta data and distributes student to a dormitory ( hall ). Below you can see my code student model along with student_meta and nextOfKin model from sequelize and also enrollment and hall model.

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require ('bcrypt');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {

    static associate({Token, NextOfKin, StudentMeta, Enrollment, Lease, Invoice, HallRoom, Hall}) {
      this.hasMany(Token, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
      this.hasMany(NextOfKin, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
      this.hasOne(StudentMeta, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
      this.hasOne(Enrollment, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" }); 
      this.hasOne(Lease, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
      this.hasMany(Invoice, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
      this.hasOne(HallRoom, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
      this.belongsTo(Hall, { foreignKey: 'hallId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
    }

    toJSON() {
      return { ...this.get(), id: undefined, password: undefined }
    }
  };

  User.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true, 
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      isEmail: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        min: 8,
      }
    },
    password_changed_at: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: null
    },
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 'student'
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'user',
    modelName: 'User',
  });

  // VALIDATE PASSWORD FROM TOKEN
  User.prototype.checkPwdValidation = async (targetPassword, password) => {
    return await bcrypt.compare(targetPassword, password);
  }

  // CHECK IF PWD HAS BEEN UPDATED AFTER JWT TOKEN SETUP
  User.prototype.changedPwdAfterCheck = function(JWTExpirationDate) {

    if(this.password_changed_at) {
      // IF NOT, COMPARE TOKEN TIMESTAMP TO USER PROFILE TIMESTAMP
      const changedTimestamp = this.password_changed_at.getTime() / 1000;
      return changedTimestamp > JWTExpirationDate; // CHANGED
    } 
    return false; // NOT CHANGED
  }

  return User;
};
```

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class StudentMeta extends Model {

    static associate({User}) {
      this.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
    }
  };
  StudentMeta.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    dob: {
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    sex: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    nationality: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    phone_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    adress: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    city: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    state_province: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    country: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    zip_code: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'student_meta',
    modelName: 'StudentMeta',
  });
  return StudentMeta;
};
```

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class NextOfKin extends Model {

    static associate({User}) {
      this.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
    }
  };
  NextOfKin.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      isEmail: true
    },
    relation: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    adress: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    phone_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'next_of_kin',
    modelName: 'NextOfKin',
  });
  return NextOfKin;
};
```

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Hall extends Model {

    static associate({HallStaff, HallRoom, User}) {
      // define association here  
      this.hasMany(User, { foreignKey: 'hallId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" })
      this.hasMany(HallStaff, { foreignKey: 'hallId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
      this.hasMany(HallRoom, { foreignKey: 'hallId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
    }

    toJSON() {
      return { ...this.get(), id: undefined }
    }
  };

  Hall.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    hall_number: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    hall_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    rooms_number: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    students_number: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    student_per_room: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    min_grade: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    max_grade: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    facilities: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    universities: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    bathroom: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    adress: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    coords: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    phone_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'hall',
    modelName: 'Hall',
  });

  return Hall;
};
```

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Enrollment extends Model {

    static associate({University, User}) {
      this.belongsTo(University, { foreignKey: 'universityId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
      this.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId', foreignKeyConstraint: true, allowNull: false, onDelete: "CASCADE" });
    }
  };

  Enrollment.init({
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    university: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    year_of_study: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    type_of_study: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    grade: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    financial_type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    nationality: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    student_gender: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'enrollment',
    modelName: 'Enrollment',
  });

  return Enrollment;
};
```

What I did until now: I managed to create the allocation process using the models: A student can have a single enrollment and an university can have multiple enrollments. The enrollment has a foreign key of universityId and userId. Based on available halls for each university, a student can be alocated in a single hall: first check is for student meta information and nextOfKin( at least one contact person from family ), and a valid enrollment. After this check, all halls are fetched and ordered DESC by grade. There is a loop that goes through each hall and perform check for number of available spaces for university, for specific hall and also check if the student is already allocated. If so, throws an error and returns.Bellow is my code for all of this.

```
exports.studentAllocation = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        // CHECK FOR STUDENT META INFORMATIONS
        const studentMetaExists = await StudentMeta.findOne({where: {userId: req.user.id}});

        if(!studentMetaExists) {
            return next(new AppError("In order to be allocated, you must update your student informations.", 404));
        }

        // CHECK FOR STUDENT KINS
        const studentKinsExists = await NextOfKin.findAll({where: {id: req.user.id}});

        if(!studentKinsExists) {
            return next(new AppError("In order to be allocated, you must update your student informations.", 404));
        }

        // IF STUDENT META AND KIN INFORMATION
        const enrollment = await Enrollment.findOne({where: {userId: req.user.id}});

        if(!enrollment) {
            return next(new AppError("In order to be allocated, you must enroll.", 404));
        }

        // GET UNIVERSITY HALLS BASED ON ENROLLMENT UNI ID
        const uniHalls = await University.findOne({
            where: { id: enrollment.universityId },
            attributes:['halls']
        });

        const hallsArr = [...uniHalls.halls];
        
        // FETCH ALL HALLS BASED ON hallsArr
        const halls = await Hall.findAll({
            where: {
                hall_name: hallsArr
            },
            order: [['min_grade', 'desc']],
            attributes: ['id', 'hall_number', 'hall_name', 'rooms_number', 'students_number', 'student_per_room', 'min_grade', 'max_grade']
        });

        // MAP HALLS AND SET CONSTRAINTS
        for (const [i, hall] of halls.entries()) {
            const studentsLimit = hall.students_number;
        
            // GET ALL STUDENTS WHERE HALL ID = THIS HALL ID ( COUNT THEM )
            const countStudents = await User.count({
                where: { hallId: hall.id }
            });

            // GET USER BASED ON ENROLLMENT
            const enrolledUser = await User.findOne({ where: { id: enrollment.userId } });

            // CHECK IF STUDENT IS ALLREADY ALLOCATED
            if(enrolledUser.hallId !== null) {
                return next(new AppError(`You are already allocated in hall ${hall.hall_name}.`, 500));
            }

            // CHECK IF THE NUMBER OF STUDENTS FROM CURRENT HALL IS GREATER THAN THE LIMIT AND CURRENT HALL IS THE LAST ONE
            if(countStudents >= studentsLimit && i === halls.length - 1) {
                return next(new AppError("You can not enroll because the limit of students for your university has been reached.", 500));
            }

            // CHECK IF THE NUMBER OF STUDENTS FROM CURRENT HALL IS GREATER THAN THE LIMIT
            if(countStudents >= studentsLimit) {
                continue;
            }

            // CHECK IF STUDENT GRADE MATCH HALL CONSTRAINTS
            if(enrollment.grade < hall.min_grade) {
                continue;
            }

            // IF THERE ARE AVAILABLE SPACES AND STUDENT IS NOT ALLOCATED YET, ALLOCATE STUDENT TO CURRENT HALL
            enrolledUser.hallId = hall.id;
            await enrolledUser.save();

            // CUSTOM ORDER
            const customOrder = (column, values, direction) => {
                let orderByClause = 'CASE ';
              
                for (let index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
                  let value = values[index];
              
                  if (typeof value === 'string') value = `'${value}'`;
              
                  orderByClause += `WHEN ${column} = ${value} THEN '${index}' `;
                }
              
                orderByClause += `ELSE ${column} END`
              
                return [Sequelize.literal(orderByClause), direction]
            };

            const allStudents = await User.findAll({
                where: {hallId: hall.id},
                include: [{
                    model: Enrollment,
                }],
                order: [
                    customOrder('type_of_study', ['licenta', 'master','doctorat'], 'ASC'),
                    customOrder('student_gender', ['female', 'male'], 'ASC'),
                    ['Enrollment', 'year_of_study', 'ASC'],
                ]
            });

            return res.status(200).json({
                status: "Success",
                data: allStudents,
            });                
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            status: err.name,
            message: `${err.message} at ${err.expiredAt}`
        }); 
    }
}
```

As you can see, I managed to accommodate students on a specific hall based on constraints and also fetch all students from a hall ordered by my constraints. I know is a lot, but I tried to make it all clear before I ask my question.

Question: Now, based on the way I ordered my students, I have to assign each student to a dorm room and find out his neighbors. In a dorm room ( hall room ), students must match the gender, and also year of study and study type: license, master and doctorate. I tried to perform a loop and group them by 2, 3, 4 based on hall but i failed. I also tried to perform a two-dimensional matrix with a for that loops students and another one that loops rooms and allocate them but i failed. I also tried with useReducer and Recursion but i did not understand that pretty well... I hope somebody can give me some steps to perform this action, or any code hint would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time, i know it's a big question.